# Password less ssh for gce

Tags: password-less

I like to know, whenever we create instace in gcp, how to set user based ssh without pem file. I am trying to find way to do password less ssh script, to do that, I need user based login. I need to suppress ( ubuntu@10.170.0.7: Permission denied (publickey).) and logged into the VM.

Do anyone help me to resolve.

I need a script to setup passwordless ssh to new VMs from exiting VM

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want with combining `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host` command and [expect](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) which is being used to create automate scripts.